# Which is the best doc to know in detail about client-go repo refactoring in Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes

I am trying to upgrade my dependencies and I have the below code which uses client-go version v2.0.0

```
import "k8s.io/client-go/pkg/version"
var subResourceServiceAndNodeProxyVersion = version.MustParse("v1.2.0")
```

Now , I am using latest version of client-go and I see that many modules are spread across api,apimachinery and kubernetes repo.

So what will be the equivalent of `version.MustParse` and `Parse`
https://github.com/kubernetes/client-go/blob/v2.0.0/pkg/version/semver.go

I did search but couldn't find anything useful.